# Find current CPU usage in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, pinvoke, cpu

I'm looking for a way to discover the current CPU usage on a WindowsCE system. 
This is running .Net Compact Framework 2.0.

Is there a way to do this via .net or via pinvoke.

I have been unable to find an answer online.

Answer (score 1):

you can try and use the opennetcf framework which has a lot of extra functionality for windows CE [check the documentation](https://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/).

After i did some more digging, it seems this tool might help : [Procman](http://www.entrek.com/procman.html)

Comment: That's a useful link but it doesn't contain a cpu usage function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah I see the best you can get is the processor type and memory usage. do you have the option to view that stats remotely?

Comment: I saw this in a different forum : "In Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 (which is freely available) you
can find a tool called "Remote Performance Monitor". After connecting
to your device the tool can be used to watch CPU usage, memory usage,
battery stats."

Comment: Although cTacke marked that as duplicate and answered, there is no really CSharp coded answer. If you are interested in working code see my cpuMon (Compact Framework) at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/12/14/mobile-development-a-remote-cpu-monitor-and-cpu-usage-analysis/